# URL's for using Xamarin.Auth with Facebook

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.ios, facebook-login, xamarin.auth

I'm trying to test out Xamarin.Auth with Facebook on Xamarin.iOS. I can login via the web view and get redirected but the `Completed` handler is never called. After some investigation, it looks like a common problem that users have is with this code from WebRedirectAuthenticator.cs

```
private bool UrlMatchesRedirect (Uri url)
{
    return url.Host == redirectUrl.Host && url.LocalPath == redirectUrl.LocalPath;
}
```

which controls whether the `Completed` event is raised.

As far as I can tell I have everything set up correctly both in code and in the Facebook developer console.

### Redirect URL's in Facebook developer console

[image: Url's in Facebook Developer Console]

### URL's

[image: Url's in code]

### Authenticator

[image: Using the authenticator in code]

However, the process never continues past this point

[image: Facebook OAuth redirect screen]

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing are you using the same account as the Facebook app / developer account is setup on?  If so try testing with a normal account.

I could be wrong but have a vague memory or hitting something similar once

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the **s** from "https". Your variable declaration should look like this:

```
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
```

Comment: No idea. It got flagged by some other community members as being "not an answer". That came to my attention, and I declined the flag as invalid. I edited the answer to hopefully prevent any further confusion.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the tip. I'm new to the community, I'll take care of the next post :)    
( sorry for my English )